# Widget launching a second instance of application

Tags: android, widget

I am having problems launching my application from my widget when it's clicked upon.
Here is a cut of some code

```
// Create an Intent to launch activity
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Entry_MainTabView.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);             
updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Widget, pendingIntent);
```

Now take the scenario.
I launch my app, exit to the home page , then click on my widget.
It launches a second instance of the application, so when I hit "back" , the application goes away and reveals the other copy. I then hit back again and finally go back to the homescreen.

How can I make the Intent only create a new instance if none already exists in ram ?

Comment: There's not 2 applications running, there's 2 of the same activities running in your application. Declare your activity as singleinstance in your manifest.

Comment: ah - didn't notice that for the manifest , now works a treat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [singleInstance and singleTask launch modes of an activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)? [This extract from Pro Android 2](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=Bam8K5SIiTkC&pg=PA465&lpg=PA465&dq=android+widget+single+instance&source=bl&ots=NGIiz5HSW1&sig=aMRdWPOZkprh6SbH3KBB-SRRFUg&hl=en&ei=WsD6TOayBYbsrAfY3c2FCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=android%20widget%20single%20instance&f=false) indicates that there is no documented way of ensuring that there is only one instance of the widget running.