# Widget launching a second instance of application - different activities

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

After reading more than 30 articles and testing more than 15 suggested solutions - i came out empty and my problem persists.

My problem is very similar to the issue discussed in:
[Widget launching a second instance of application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356146/widget-launching-a-second-instance-of-application)

I have activity A - the launcher activity .
A launches activity B for result.
User clicks home button - than starts the application from a widget (the widget launches activity A).
The user get the A activity, clicks back , gets B activity , clicks another back get A again with different data - since B returned its result.
What i really want is that the widget will not launch a new instance for Activity A - I would want it to identify Activity A already activity and start it (in the case i described its the chain A==>B).

Already tried All the flags(4) in PendingIntent.getActivity.
I tried flagging the B launch with 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

And put in my manifest "allowtaskreparenting" for the application and paramter android:launchMode="singleTop" in Activity A.